# Streamreader returns null for a field that has a value

Tags: c#, asp.net, stream, streamreader

I'm using a streamreader to get the values from a url. It all works fine for 20+ fields, but I have run into an issue with one particular field that shows as having a value but returns null, as highlighted in the below image.

[image]

It's not a permission issue as all the other fields come through fine (the above screenshot only shows a cut down version for ease) Also both the web browser and the c# application run as the same user.

```
        string url = "test.com";
        WebRequest myReq = WebRequest.Create(url);
        string credentials = "username:pwd";
        CredentialCache mycache = new CredentialCache();
        myReq.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + 
        Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(credentials));
        myReq.Method = "GET";
        myReq.ContentType = "application/json";
        WebResponse wr = myReq.GetResponse();
        Stream receiveStream = wr.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

I'm really stuck for what the reason could be for it being returned as null. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction!

Comment: streamreader does not return null, it just returns a string, So you might want to look at whatever is generating the response if the string does not correspond to your expectations..

Comment: as per @JonasH I am a little confused. StreamReader is just reading the bytes and giving you a string. It knows nothing about "fields".  This appears to the json, so I would expect there to be some json deserialize something in there. Modern HttpClient has some simple patterns for this.
DateTime in json is "odd". It is serialized as a string. Serializers will parse it to get back to the DateTime.
It's unclear what tools you are using there. But an "html viewer" is probably no going to understand json (?)